# nvidia refuses to wake up

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

Whenever i try to suspend my laptop (Lenovo Y530 with hybrid graphics (Intel & NVIDIA 1050Ti)) i face this issue:

```
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Display engine push buffer channel allocation failed: 0x65 (Call timed out [NV_ERR_TIMEOUT])
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Failed to allocate display engine core DMA push buffer
kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000070
kernel: IP: [<ffffffffc20619ae>] _nv002366kms+0x5e/0x100 [nvidia_modeset]
```

I tried both the solutions in this link but to no avail. i tried to identify if it is a distro, kernel or even a specific device issue thing. but it turns out it is only but only a nvidia problem.

I am using nvidia-driver-455; i went to nvidia xserver settings and changed the graphics card from nvidia to intel and rebooted and tried suspending and it worked without a single issue.

unfortunately i cannot suspend my device under any circumstances as long as i am using nvidia.

I tried to use nouvea but -for some reasons- it does not work perfectly on my device (it specifically does not refresh the screen at all, just a picture displayed).

Comment: Try updating BIOS, Chipset (video needs Chipset) and Video drivers with the Lenovo System Update app. Restart and test.

Comment: please, can you give instructions to that?

Comment: @John i used this link (https://support.lenovo.com/eg/en/downloads/ds012808-lenovo-system-update-for-windows-10-7-32-bit-64-bit-desktop-notebook-workstation) but to no avail

Comment: You may need to stick with Intel Graphics. I do not know how well your laptop supports Linux.

Comment: @john i know NVIDIA and Linux do no go a long but is there really a "linux compatability" that differs from laptop to another?

Answer (score 1):

Switching from `460` to `450` nvidia driver works for me on Ubuntu 20.10, GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile, Unity gui.

Answer (score 0):

I used the
[NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)
to search for Linux drivers for the NVIDIA 1050Ti.

This gave me the
[Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/164073/en-us)
for 64-bit computers.

If installing this driver fixes the problem, all is good.
However, ensure that you can go back to the previous driver in case it doesn't
work on your computer.

Comment: i download it using software & updates (`software-properties-gtk`) are they the same?

Comment: No, the driver in the repository is often behind the one from the manufacturer. However, if it works fine then no reason not to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue. this issue is simply because there is a bug in NVIDIA drivers that prevents booting back from a hibernation.

The solution is simple, force to shutdown or do not try to hibernate before you `prime-select intel`, if that does not work, i have never found a better solution other than `purge nvidia-driver-*`.

Update after 1 year: this issue persists in `nvidia-driver-470` and to circumvent such issue, do not sleep your device unless you purge `nvidia`entirely as following:

`sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-470 && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo apt-get purge -y`

You need to remove it using `apt` and then clean then you need to manually remove any traces in `dpkg` as leaving them will prevent you from suspending/hibernating as the `suspend` and `hibernate` services are still in `systemd`.